# Ember simple fake service not showing up on page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am just trying to get a service set up and ready for a REST API.  I'm just using fake data just to see if I can pull it into the controller.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to display the information.

I went through [this documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/) but I'm not able to see my return

I have my service as `report.js`

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    reports: [100, 96, 92, 74, 65, 64, 42, 21, 20, 19, 10, 4],
});
```

Then I have a controller `report.js`

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    reports: Ember.inject.service('report')
});
```

Then in my hbs file, I have:

```
<div>
    {{#each reports as |report|}}
    <span>{{report}}</span>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

When I load the page, I don't see anything, though I should see a group of numbers.  If I go into the ember inspector in chrome, I can go to `container > service > reports` and I see all of the numbers as an ember service subclass.

How do I get my numbers from the service, through the controller into the html template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
{{#each reports.reports as |report|}}
```

The service name is accessed via the "reports" property (the name you use to `inject`) and then that service has a `reports` property which is where the values are. Hence the `reports.reports` is needed